# How to include variable in a test case in scope of tested object

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, require

I have a test case which goes something like that:

```
const css = require('../css');

it('should include css', function(){
    var document = jsdom('<html><head></head></html>');
    return css('/bootstrap.min.css');
});
```

The actual css module looks like:

```
module.exports = function(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        const link = document.createElement('link');
        link.href = url;
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    });
}
```

The code will be executed in the browser, so the document will be available, but tests are run locally, and I want to use a fake document which I generate with JSDOM module. Is it possible to make node look for document from the test case's scope? ATM I'm explicitly passing doc, but I want to find to proxy the scope.

Comment: It looks like you are using jasmine. Why not use spyOn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use global.document = ... to export global variable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve this by exporting a function that takes a url and a `document` object.  Then your production code could pass in it's real document object, and your test could configure a test object to assert on:

```
module.exports = function(document, url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        const link = document.createElement('link');
        link.href = url;
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
        resolve(document);
    });
}



it('should append link', function() {
   var document = jsdom('<html><head></head></html>');
   css(document, someUrl).then(function(mutatedDocument) {
     assert(mutatedDocument).containsURL(someUrl);
   });
});
```

Comment: yeah I ended up including document as an argument but I was wondering if it is possible to expose the scope for the require ...